# Creating a BoundingFrustum from 8 corners

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

XNA contains a BoundingFrustum class which defines a frustum and facilitates collisions with Rays and other objects. However, the Frustum can only be constructed with a Matrix. I have a certain object which is created in a frustum shape using 8 vertices; what kind of Matrix should I create from these vertices in order to create a Frustum to represent it?

The object in question is a chunk of a sphere-- 4 points on the sphere's surface in the form of a square, extending downward into the origin of the sphere.

Comment: Are you just trying to check if something is on the surface of the sphere and within the square, or do you need to be checking the interior of the sphere too?

Comment: Interior as well.  The sphere is made of frustum blocks, I'm trying to do picking by chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nic's inspiration and the help of a friend, I was able to write this class which represents a region defined by 8 points which has flat sides, such as a frustum or cube.

[Here is the class](http://pastebin.com/vAMzsinc).

It's important to note that, when passing in the constructor parameters, you choose a vantage point from which to view your region and stick with it.

Hope this helps anyone else who may run into this (obscure) problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Normally to use a `BoundingFrustum` you pass it a Matrix that is a view matrix multiplied by a projection matrix:

`BoundingFrustum frustum = new BoundingFrustum(this.viewMatrix * this.projectionMatrix);`

There is no easy way to use that class to do what you describe unless you're particularly skilled in creating a Matrix by hand that combines what would normally be in a view matrix and projection matrix into something that represents your 8 corners.

What I would recommend is writing an algorithm to solve your problem.

```
// Do something like this for all 8 sides of the frustum, if the sphere lies outside
// of any of the 8 sides then it isn't in the frustum.

// Each plane will have a normal direction (the direction the inside is facing)
Vector3 normal = Vector3.UnitY;

// Creates a plane
Plane plane = new Plane(normal, 20.0f);

BoundingSphere sphere = new BoundingSphere(Vector3.Zero, 10.0f);

// This type is an enum that will tell you which side the intersection is on
PlaneIntersectionType type = sphere.Intersects(plane);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about using plane intersection to define the region.  It seems rather complicated. I'm trying to intersect this region with a Ray, so I won't get an IntersectionType, but I guess I could use the dot products somehow...  Since both planes and rays are infinite, it's difficult to efficiently compute, I think.

Also, I wonder if I can't use the property of my sphere to construct a view and projection matrix for the region.  I wish I knew more about how those matrices were constructed.